# attempt datareader is close, but i never close these reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I develop C# application, I get stuck off reader is close in my program, the reader in cekprevnext is errot, it say "invalid attempt read, when reader is close", so this is all my code :

```
private void cekprevnext()
    {
        ambilsoal();
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmds = new MySqlCommand("Select * from jawab_soal WHere SoalID='"+SOALID+"'", con);
        MySqlDataReader drs = cmds.ExecuteReader();
        if (drs.HasRows)
        {
            while (drs.Read()) // ==> This attempt reader close
            {
                jwbsudah = drs["jambilsoal"].ToString();
                if (jwbA.Text == jwbsudah)
                {
                    jwbA.Checked = true;
                }
                else if (jwbB.Text == jwbsudah)
                {
                    jwbB.Checked = true;
                }
                else if (jwbC.Text == jwbsudah)
                {
                    jwbC.Checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    jwbD.Checked = true;
                }
            }
        }  
        con.Close();
    }
```

this my ambil soal method :

```
private void ambilsoal()
    {
        jwbA.Checked = false;
        jwbB.Checked = false;
        jwbC.Checked = false;
        jwbD.Checked = false;
        if (count == jml)
        {
            btnnext.Enabled = false;
            btnprev.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if (count == 1)
        {
            btnprev.Enabled = false;
            btnnext.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnnext.Enabled = true;
            btnprev.Enabled = true;
        }
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * From soal Where KatID='" + KatID + "' AND NoSoal='"+count+"'", con);
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                soalTampil.Text = dr["Pertanyaan"].ToString();
                jwbA.Text = dr["A"].ToString();
                jwbB.Text = dr["B"].ToString();
                jwbC.Text = dr["C"].ToString();
                jwbD.Text = dr["D"].ToString();
                SOALID = dr["SoalID"].ToString();
                jwbbelum = dr["Jawaban"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            con.Close();
            RadMessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

can someone helpme ?

Comment: Start using the c# using-clause and try to execute cekprevnext() without executing  ambilsoal().

Comment: Your connection object seems to be stored in a global variable (which is a bad idea).  Is it possible that something else is closing the connection?  What if you create a new connection inside the `cekprevnext`?  Do you still get the exception?